# Color Quantization using K Means (making sense of code)

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, k-means

Can someone please explain what the '`label`' is in `ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)` ?

also what exactly is happening here:

```
# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))
```

Compelete code:

```
img = cv2.imread('home.jpg')
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 8
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
```

Comment: kmeans is a clustering algorithms, the labels is in which cluster does the point belongs too. So one per sample.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to the documentation https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88.

The labels are the cluster indices for every sample.